# "A, together with B" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which is the correct form of the following structure?

> A, together with B, provide an efficient means of...

or

> A, together with B, provides an efficient means of...

Certainly, "A provides", and "A and B provide". My intuition tells me that the second form is correct because A is the subject and is singular.

Comment: I find a little ambiguity in the phrase "together with". Does it mean "like", or "when combined with" in your example?

Comment: @MARGANA A common problem with such structures (though they're widely used). Bacon and eggs and pineapple are my favourite foods.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oxford comma?

Comment: @anthony-arnold I'd certainly disambiguate. In your example, for instance, I'd choose 'The combination of A and B provides...' or 'Both A and B provide ...'. We've covered the "serial _and_'s" case before; 'Bacon & eggs and pineapple are my favourite foods.' is one  work-around.